# Padding Multiple Log4Net Pattern Wildcards Together

Tags: log4net

I want to include the class and method name in our log output with a combined fixed width to look something like;

```
ClassA.MethodA            - message
AnotherClass.AnotherMethod- message
WhateeverClass.Meth       - message
SomeReallyLongClass.AndAreallyLongMethod- message
```

Is it possible to somehow combine the 2 wildcards say like `%-50class.method`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no builtin support for padding a combination of conversion patterns.

Your best option is to implement a custom `PatternLayoutConverter` returning the combined result of `%class` and `%method`. On this single one, you can apply a padding specifier in the regular way.

**Pattern layout**

```cs
namespace PFX
{   
    public class ClassAndMethodPatternConverter : PatternLayoutConverter
    {
        protected override void Convert(TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            var info = loggingEvent.LocationInformation;
            var text = $"{info.ClassName}.{info.MethodName}";
            writer.Write(text);
        }
    }
}
```

**Registration and usage in a `Log4net` configuration file**

`PFX.ClassAndMethodIdPatternConverter, MyLibrary` represents the full name of the pattern converter above, composed of the namespace, class and assembly .

```xml
<appender name="consoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender" >
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <converter>
            <name value="classandmethod" />
            <type value="PFX.ClassAndMethodPatternConverter, MyLibrary" />
        </converter>
        <conversionPattern value="%date | %logger | %level | %-50classandmethod | %message | %exception%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```